# Excel's AVERAGEIFS() in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to duplicate what you'd do with AVERAGEIFS function in Excel on my dataset:

```
EG_df <- data.frame(id = c("red_blue", "white_blue", "red_yellow","white_yellow", "brown_blue", "brown_yellow"), 
                    StartDate = as.Date(c('2019-1-1','2019-3-1','2019-7-1','2018-1-1','2018-3-1','2018-7-1')),
                    EndDate = as.Date(c('2019-6-1','2019-12-1','2019-8-1','2018-1-1','2018-3-1','2018-7-1')),
                    avg_Value = NA
                    )
```

---

```
source <- data.frame(source.id = c("red_blue", "red_blue", "red_blue","brown_yellow", "brown_yellow", "brown_yellow"),
                      source.Date = as.Date(c('2019-1-1','2019-2-1','2019-3-1','2018-7-1','2018-8-1','2018-9-1')),
                     source.Value = c(22,56,32,31,14,7)
                    )
```

**Logic I need to fill in** `EG.df$avg_Value` :

For each row in **`EG_df`**, return the average value of `source.value` when `source.Date` is between `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

The Excel Formula, for clarification:

> =AVERAGEIFS(source.value, source.id, id, source.Date, ">="&StartDate, source.Date, ">="&EndDate)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the `tidyverse`

```
dplyr::inner_join(source,EG_df,by = c("source.id"="id")) %>%
  dplyr::filter(source.Date >= StartDate,
                source.Date <= EndDate) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(source.id,StartDate,EndDate) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(avg_Value = mean(source.Value))
```

Comment: If you're going to write an answer all with one library, I'd recommend loading the package `library(dplyr)` at the top of your code, and removing `dplyr::` since the use of `dplyr` is implicit. Typically the `package::function` notation is useful if you're using multiple libraries, and want to add clarity to where the function comes from.

Comment: that's a fair point. I generally take the approach that I don't know what is occurring elsewhere in their code, so I am explicit to prevent the namespace collision.

Comment: True, although in the context of this website, OP should be providing a [mcve], which should give us the context to anticipate any namespace collision, without having to preemptively account for it.

Comment: Hi @Wil , thank you!
My 'EG_df' has many more columns than the few in the example, and when selecting some of those to be added in 'summarise()' it does not accept one of those, returning the error:
'Error: Column anotherID is unknown'
_Could it be because_ 'anotherID' _is present in both_ 'EG_df' _and_ 'source' ?
If that's the case, how should I properly indicate the 'EG_df$anotherID' column? (I tried with the dollar sign and that's what I get:
'Error: Column anotherID must be length 34260 (the number of rows) or one, not 23160'
Thank you in advance for any further help!

Comment: What is the role of anotherID in your data? Is it a unique identifier, a measurement of some sort that needs to be aggregated, or just another attribute of the data that you would like included in the output? This [dplyr article](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/two-table.html) may be helpful for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty efficiently with a non-equi join:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(source); setDT(EG_df)

EG_df[, avg_Value := 
  source[copy(.SD), on=.(source.id = id, source.Date >= StartDate, source.Date <= EndDate), mean(x.source.Value), by=.EACHI]$V1
]

             id  StartDate    EndDate avg_Value
1:     red_blue 2019-01-01 2019-06-01  36.66667
2:   white_blue 2019-03-01 2019-12-01        NA
3:   red_yellow 2019-07-01 2019-08-01        NA
4: white_yellow 2018-01-01 2018-01-01        NA
5:   brown_blue 2018-03-01 2018-03-01        NA
6: brown_yellow 2018-07-01 2018-07-01  31.00000
```

(There are NAs since I'm just using the excerpt `source` provided rather than the full table.)

*How it works*

`x[i, j]` subsets using `i` and then evaluates `j`, inside of which `.SD` refers to the `S`ubset of `D`ata.

When `x` and `i` are both tables, `x[i, on=, j, by=.EACHI]` is a join, with `on=` specifying the join conditions, and `j` evaluated for each row of `i`.

Because `j = mean(x.source.Value)` returns an unnamed column, it gets the default name of `V1`.

Inside `j` of `x[i, j]`, `v := val` creates or modifies column `v` by assigning `val` to it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the dplyr Librarie

```
library(dyplr)

df = EG_df %>% 
     left_join(source, by = c('id' = 'source.id')) %>% 
     filter((StartDate <= source.Date) & (source.Date <= EndDate)) %>% 
     group_by(id, StartDate, EndDate) %>% 
     summarise(value = mean(source.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `base` package running a `merge > subset > aggregate` for the averages by id group and date range. Then `merge` this resultset back to original dataset.

```
# MERGE > SUBSET > AGGREGATE
agg_df <- aggregate(cbind(avgValue=source.Value) ~ id + StartDate + EndDate,
                    subset(merge(EG_df, source, by.x="id", by.y="source.id", all.x=TRUE),
                           source.Date >= StartDate & source.Date <= EndDate),
                    FUN=mean)

# MERGE WITH ORIGINAL DATASET
merge(EG_df, agg_df, by=c("id", "StartDate", "EndDate"), all.x=TRUE)

#             id  StartDate    EndDate avgValue
# 1   brown_blue 2018-03-01 2018-03-01       NA
# 2 brown_yellow 2018-07-01 2018-07-01 31.00000
# 3     red_blue 2019-01-01 2019-06-01 36.66667
# 4   red_yellow 2019-07-01 2019-08-01       NA
# 5   white_blue 2019-03-01 2019-12-01       NA
# 6 white_yellow 2018-01-01 2018-01-01       NA
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/ELNFO86439)

---

Aside - This is similar to SQL's [greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem (official StackOverflow tag) where the *agg_df* would be a subquery or CTE joined back to original table.